# How to find what the sum of this infinite series is.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following series:

$\sum_{n\geq3} \frac{4n-3}{n^3-4n}$

which I've simplified into the following:

$\frac{3}{4}\sum_{n\geq3}{ \frac{1}{n}} + \frac{5}{8}\sum_{n\geq3} \frac{1}{n-2} - \frac{11}{8}\sum_{n\geq3} \frac{1}{n+2}$

And this is where I'm stuck... How do I calculate the total sum?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are **not allowed** to split up the sum like you have done it (unless you have finite series?) !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

Do a change of index to express all the sums on the form $\sum_n \frac 1 n$ and simplify.

**Edit** First notice as user127001 said you are **not allowed** to split the sum on three divergent sum so the **key** is to use a *partial sum* and finaly you pass to the limit.

Now from your work
$$\frac{3}{4}\sum_{n=3}^N{ \frac{1}{n}} + \frac{5}{8}\sum_{n=3}^N \frac{1}{n-2} - \frac{11}{8}\sum_{n=3}^N \frac{1}{n+2}=\frac{3}{4}\sum_{n=3}^N{ \frac{1}{n}}+\frac{5}{8}\sum_{n=1}^{N-2} \frac{1}{n}- \frac{11}{8}\sum_{n=5}^{N+2} \frac{1}{n}$$

and we cancel all the terms from $n=5$ to $n=N-2$ and we pass to the limit $N\to\infty$ to conclude.

Comment: I tried that but since it didn't help me much further I assumed it wasn't of much use, but this changes all sums to $\frac{1}{n}$ and the indexes to respectively (starting from the second series) $n=1$ and $n=5$. How do I continue from here?

Comment: I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Following @SamiBenRomdhane's hint, all the sums cancel out starting at $\frac{1}{5}$, so the sequence of partial sums converges to the finite sum $$ \frac{3}{4}(1/3 + 1/4) + \frac{5}{8}(1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4)$$

Comment: Thanks! I'm having a bit of trouble finding the right latex code to edit my original question...

Comment: @Joshua I edited my answer adding some details.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{3}^{\infty} \frac{ 4n-3 }{ n^3-4n }=\\
\sum_{3}^{\infty} \frac{ 4n-3 }{ n(n^2-4) }=\\
\sum_{3}^{\infty} \frac{ 4n }{ n(n-2)(n+2) }+\sum_{3}^{\infty} \frac{ -3 }{ n(n-2)(n+2) }=\\
4\sum_{3}^{\infty} \frac{ 1 }{ (n-2)(n+2) }-3\sum_{3}^{\infty} \frac{ +1 }{ n(n-2)(n+2)}$$

Comment: $$\frac{ 4 }{ 4 }\sum_{3}^{\infty} (\frac{ 1 }{ (n-2) }-\frac{ 1 }{ (n+2) })-\frac{ 3 }{ 4 }\sum_{3}^{\infty} \frac{ +1 }{ (n-2)n}-\frac{ +1 }{ n(n+2)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple generalization: denote $S_n=\sum_{j=3}^{n}\frac{1}{j}$. Then your whole expression becomes (after partial fraction expansion):
$$
V=\lim_{n \to \infty}\bigg(\frac{3}{4}S_n+\frac{5}{8}\bigg(S_n+\frac{1}{2} +1 +\varphi_1(n)\bigg)-\frac{11}{8}\bigg(S_n-\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4} +\varphi_2(n)\bigg)\bigg)=\frac{5}{8} \cdot \frac{3}{2}+\frac{11}{8}\cdot \frac{1}{12}
$$
because $\varphi_1(n)$ and $\varphi_2(n) \ \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.